# Prove that there exists a triangle which can be cut into 2005 congruent triangles.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I thought maybe we can start with congruent triangle and try to cut it similar to how we create a Sierpinski's Triangle?  However, the number of smaller triangles we get is a power of $4$ so it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: This is from APMO 2005.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The decomposition is possible because $2005 = 5\cdot 401$ and both $5$ and $401$ are primes of the form $4k+1$. This allow $2005$ to be written as a sum of squares.

$$2005 = 22^2 + 39^2 = 18^2+41^2$$

For any integer $n = p^2 + q^2$ that can be written as a sum of squares. 
Consider a right-angled triangle $ABC$ with 
$$AB = p\sqrt{n}, AC = q\sqrt{n}\quad\text{ and }\quad BC = n$$
Let $D$ on $BC$ be the foot of attitude at $A$. It is easy to
see $\triangle DBA$ and $\triangle DAC$ are similar to $\triangle ABC$ with

$$BD = p^2, AD = pq\quad\text{ and }\quad CD = q^2$$
One can split $\triangle DBA$ into $p^2$ and $\triangle DAC$ into $q^2$
triangles with sides $p, q$ and $\sqrt{n}$.

As an example, following is a subdivision of a triangle into $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$ congruent triangles.

[image: tiling by 13 congruent triangles]

In the literature, this is known as a biquadratic tiling of a triangle. For more information about subdividing triangles into congruent triangles, look at answers in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67199/subdivision-of-triangles-into-congruent-triangles/67204#67204). In particular, the list of papers by Michael Beeson there. The construction described here is based on what I have learned from one of Michael's papers.

Answer (score 12):

Since $2005$ is the sum of two squares, there exists this sort of triangle. In a contest setting, if you're trying to show $2005$ is a sum of two squares, realize that $2005=401\cdot 5$. Since 401 and 5 are sums of squares, we know that their product is also a sum of squares.

Now in general if we have $n=x^2+y^2$, let our triangle be an $x$ by $y$ right triangle. Then, we can split this triangle along the altitude to the hypotenuse, which gives us two similar triangles with hypotenuses $x$ and $y$ respectively. Finally, we can decompose each of these into $x^2$ and $y^2$ similar right triangles with hypotenuses $1$, via a stretched version of the following picture.

[image: Triangle Tiling]

Comment: I know this sum of squares is a sufficient condition, but I'm not sure if it's necessary. Any thoughts on this? As a particular example, would $3$ or $7$ work?

Comment: The $30-60-90$ triangle can be divided into three triangles.  Start by bisecting the 60 angle.

Comment: Alright, so $3$ works. I also just thought of the construction of connecting vertices of an equilateral triangle to the center, which would create three congruent triangles. Any others?

Comment: It seems Michael Beeson has proved that $7$ is impossible recently. [this](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/NoSevenTiling.pdf) appears on his web site, not yet available on arXiv...

Comment: @achillehui: Gosh — a lovely paper, and very hot off the press!