# Cutting a triangle into 101 congruent triangles

Tags: geometry

Determine whether there is a triangle that can be cut into 101 congruent triangles.

How do you approach a problem like that? I started with a right triangle and tried several ways to cut it. Unfortunately, I can't find the rule that can then be extrapolated to 101 triangles. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is very informal, but if you look at small cases, say up to 20, it seems that this can only be done if we want to divide the triangle in 4, 9, or 16 congruent triangles. So my guess is that 101 is not possible for not being a perfect square. The trick now is how to properly justify all that.

Comment: $n = 101$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$, so we can write it as a sum of two squares $101 = 10^2+1^2$. For $n$ of this form, you can find triangle decompositible into $n$ triangles by a procedure illustrated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3013756).

Answer (score 2):

A right triangle with a 10:1 ratio between the legs.

Draw the altitude to the hypotenuse. This sets off a small piece which is similar to the large piece, with the large piece being 100 times the small one in area. The large piece is then divided into 100 parts equalling the small one using triangular coordinate gridding.

If $n$ is a sum of two squares, then a properly constructed right triangle may be divided into $n$ cobgruent pieces by a method similar to the one given here.